# What are the licensing limitations for using SharePoint Online as a service for public facing non SharePoint sites?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have just come across an article about using SharePoint Online as a service.

https://bob1german.com/2015/07/02/sharepoint-as-a-service/

Does anyone know what the licensing limitations are for using SharePoint Online services - eg client side api's e.g. rest services - for non SharePoint public facing web site? Is it allowed?

Many thanks!

Comment: Anything outside of the public anonymous sites (which are no longer available) require authentication, which means a license is necessary.